# How do I make Python read certain portion of the text and make it stop where I want it to

Tags: python

So I have this homework problem, where I need to count each letter characters in certain sections. 
Sample file:

```
>Rosalind_4451
TGTGCTGAGAATTTGCACCACTCCCGTGTCGATGGTATGAGGGAACTGGTTGTAGAACTG
CGACATTACTTTCTGAGACGCAAGGCGTACAGCCAAATGTGAAGTACAAACCAAGAAGTT
CGGGCCGGTCGTTAAGTATCCCGCATACCACACCTTGAATGGAACCCGTCGGGCCCGGGT
TTTTTAAGGGGTTTAACACACCAGACTAAGGCGTTTTCTGACTTGGAGTCGAGTCGATGG
GATGTACCTATCGAAAGAGGTACTCTATATTTGTACCGTGCAG
>Rosalind_6341
CGACAGGCTCTTTAAATTGCGAAGTGTGCCATCCTACCGCATATGCCTAGCCTAATCTTG
AGCTCGAAACCGGAAATGGAAGCACACCAATGTCTCTCCGAGCTACTGTCCATCTACGTC
ATTGCTGACGTCATATGGGCATTAGTTCCTAATCGTGATAGCGAAGGCGGTTGCGTATAC
GGCTGGTGTGTTCGGGCCAATAACGTAGAAGTATCAACATGACAGCCGTCGTGGGGAACC
```

How do I make Python count characters in the 4451 section and 6341 section?
The file varies each time, so I couldn't just manually make it count the lines with letters

Also, here is my code

```
txt = open (input ())
lines = txt.readlines ()

for lines in txt:
if lines == ">Rosalind_9690":
#fin = txt.seek(">Rosalind_9690")
#data1= fin.readlines("Rosalind_4299" to "Rosalind_9690")
    a = lines.count("A")
    g = lines.count("G")
    c = lines.count("C")
    t = lines.count("T")
    float (a)
    float (g)
    float (c)
    float (t)

CG_con = (g+c)/(a+g+c+t)
print (CG_con)
```

Comment: The varying format is not clear.  Can you be more explicit.  Also, are the section delimiters on separate lines?

Comment: No, they are in the same file. The file is different each time I try to do this homework

Comment: The question is whether the sections are on the same line, not in the same file.

Comment: Nope, they are not on the same line

Comment: @DannyXu so the section delimiters are on separate lines.  Is the letter content on a single line or is is spread across multiple lines?

Comment: Spread across multiple lines

Answer (score 2):

A dictionary could be used to hold the id and the bases. If you know beforehand the wanted ids, you could loop through the dictionary (by wanted ids) and count the bases for each id

You can make use of **Counter** from collections to count the bases for each sequence.

```
from collections import Counter

d = {} # dictionary to hold fasta data

file = input('Filename: ')

with open(file, 'r') as fasta:
    for line in fasta:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith('>'):
            id = line
            d[id] = ''
        else:
            d[id] += line

wanted = ['>Rosalind_4451', '>Rosalind_6341']

for id in wanted:
    print(id)
    seen = Counter(d[id])
    CG_com = (seen.get('G', 0) + seen.get('C', 0)) / sum(seen.values())
    print(format(CG_com, '.4f'))
```

For your data, output I received was:

```
>Rosalind_4451
0.4912
>Rosalind_6341
0.5042
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment! Can you please explain what 'r' does in open(file,'r')?  Also, what does rstrip() do? Finally, can you please also explain what seen.get('G',0) does? and how come seen.values() doesn't have the zero in it? Sorry in advanced for that many questions. Just started learning Python

Comment: For last, what is '.4f' in print(format(CG_com, '.4f'))?

Comment: @Danny Xu `'.4f'` is the `format` specifier which, when `format` is given to `print`, will print the result with 4 decimal places, (like `0.4912`). I used 4 but you can set it to however many decimal places you want.

Comment: @Danny Xu The 'r' tells python to open the file for reading. It is not necessary but is good practice to say it. To open a file for writing, you would use 'w'.

Comment: @Danny Xu `rstrip()` removes the newline character from the line just read.

Comment: @Danny Xu  `seen.get('G', 0)` retrieves the count of G bases in the sequence. If there were no Gs to find, it would use zero as a default value.. `sum(seen.values())` get the sum of all bases found in a sequence. You should probably fins a good book on Python that would be helpful for you  `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

You can `import re` and use `re.split` to split the different section assuming they follow the same format and then use `.count()` on each section

Comment: Well they don't follow the same format. Every time I download the file from the homework website it is different. So I can't manually count the lines and split them

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following regex to identify if the line contains the section header (or call it a delimiter in our case):

> '>\w+\_\d+\n'

This will pass for the delimiters of format >Rosalind_4451 and >Rosalind_6341 and similar ones.

Whenever you find a match in a line, re-initialize the count to 0 for all alphabets. Hope this helps.

P.S : make sure to use the following statement to import regex.

```
import re
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your code slightly:

```
# Automatically closes file at end, good practice
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as txt:

    lines = txt.readlines()
    for ii in range(0, len(lines) // 2, 2):

        # String objects have a built-in method to see if it starts with a substring
        if lines[ii].startswith(">Rosalind_9690"):

            # Cast to float right away
            a = float(lines[ii+1].count("A"))
            g = float(lines[ii+1].count("G"))
            c = float(lines[ii+1].count("C"))
            t = float(lines[ii+1].count("T"))

            CG_con = (g+c)/(a+g+c+t)
            print (CG_con)
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex pattern, you could do this without needing to iterate every line:

```
import re

txt = open(input()).read()

matchObj = re.search(r'>Rosalind_4451\n([AGTC\n]+)', txt) # group 1 between ()
match = matchObj.group(1) # get group 1 of match object (AGTCGT...) as string

a = float(match.count('A'))
g = float(match.count('G'))
c = float(match.count('C'))
t = float(match.count('T'))

CG_con = (g + c) / (a + g + c + t)
print(CG_con)
```

You can also set any ID you want by using an `f-string`:

```
ID = '4451'
matchObj = re.search(rf'>Rosalind_{ID}\n([AGTC\n]+)', txt)
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The code works, but I don't quite understand it. First of all, can you please explain what that match line mean? Second of all, when I first tried to run my code listed above, it wasn't printing a value. Why is that?

Comment: Also, what is  .group(1)

Comment: @DannyXu I have edited the previous snippet for better readability, hopefully it is easier to understand. Did you forget to change the id (`4451`) from the regex search?

Answer (score 0):

No need to overly complicate it, you can use re to find counts of patterns (i.e. a letter), and a handy function called `findall` which returns a list of all instances. Also, it seems from your description and comments that you want to be adding these values for each line? It's not entirely clear, but if you want to keep a running count of each instance per line per file, you have to make sure you are adding the new count to the old count

```
import re

a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
for lines in txt:
    if lines == ">Rosalind_9690":
        # adding the re.IGNORECASE flag will match lower and upper case instances
        a += len(re.findall('a', lines, re.IGNORECASE))
        g += len(re.findall('g', lines, re.IGNORECASE))
        c += len(re.findall('c', lines, re.IGNORECASE))
        t += len(re.findall('t', lines, re.IGNORECASE))
```

Just using variables to hold the count isn't that fancy though, and we might find it easier later if we use a dict to store them:

```
import re

# use a name that describes the content, I'm assuming the letters 
# are nucleobases
nucleobase_count = {
    'a': 0,
    'b': 0,
    'c': 0,
    'd': 0
}

for lines in txt:
    if lines == ">Rosalind_9690":
        # adding the re.IGNORECASE flag will match lower and upper 
        # case instances
        nucleobase_count['a'] += len(re.findall('a', lines, re.IGNORECASE))
        nucleobase_count['g'] += len(re.findall('g', lines, re.IGNORECASE))
        nucleobase_count['c'] += len(re.findall('c', lines, re.IGNORECASE))
        nucleobase_count['t'] += len(re.findall('t', lines, re.IGNORECASE))
```